# SVG use element href referring to element outside of shadowRoot?

Tags: html, svg, shadow-dom

Is there a way though for an SVGUseElement inside of a shadowRoot to refer to a fragment *outside* of the shadowRoot, in the surrounding html document?

e.g.

```
<ele>
    shadow
        <svg...
            <use href="#frag"...
</ele>
<svg>     
    <rect id="frag"...
</svg>
```

Relatedly/Alternatively are interactions between shadowDom and SVGUseElement's `href` specced somewhere?

Comment: I believe this was fixed in Firefox 77.

Comment: Hm. This moment, referring to fragments outside a shadowTree is consistently a no-go across FF/Chrome/Safari. (Personally, I think this behavior is preferable as a default / don't think it's just a bug.)

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the exact same thing.
The problem is that where you have `<use href="#frag"` it is referencing an element in the same document, Shadow DOM is basically another document within a document, like an `iframe` (as I understand it), so the element `#frag` does not exist.

I am using [LitElement](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) and the solution I came up with is to place the main `<svg>` within the `<ele>` and manually append it to the shadow root using JavaScript:
(I also tried using `<slot>`, but they are also outside the shadow DOM)

```html
<ele>
  <svg>     
    <rect id="frag"/>
  </svg>
<ele>
```

Then in JavaScript use the [firstUpdated](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#firstupdated):

```js
firstUpdated() {
  if (this.childElementCount > 0) {
    let children = this.children;
    for (let child of children) {
        child.remove();
        this.shadowRoot.append(child);
    }
  }
}
```

Wit LitElement you can also [Specify the render root](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#renderroot) this will mean that the shadow root (document within a document) is never created and should also solve the problem.

Hope that works for you! :-D

Comment: Thanks but I can't accept for few reasons: To clarify, it's understood that the shadow root is isolated from the rest of doc and that a fragment reference inside of a SR can't refer out -- normally. Grabbing the svg and injecting is admittedly a potential work around in some cases, but a primary point of the use element is to re-present another element without having to programmatically create additional copies -- if we're ok with doing that, we might abandon 'use' all together. That may not be ideal if we want live representation.

Comment: Also, crossing the shadow-root is core to the question so just not using a shadow is a no-go.

Answer (score 0):

None. After spending a couple of days working out this problem, I found out that creating a component for the purpose of serving svg icons worked best, as [outlined by Dany Engelman in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74460194/6336270).

Here is how creating the component was approached:

1. a web component called `app-svg-icon` was created.
2. The component receives the attributes `icon`, `class`, and `viewBox`.
3. An `svg` element is drawn as its innerHTML using the `icon` attribute in place of `use`.
4. The icon can be found in a global variable containing all of the svg icons.

In other words, the `use` feature was replaced with a global variable containing all of the `svg` symbols.

Web component [can be found in this Codepen](https://codepen.io/glorious73/pen/PoaeVra).

[image: svg icon component on code pen]