# How to use JavaScript variables in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables, svg

I have 3 SVGs that I will use often and in a different place on the site.
I need to put these in the SVG-1, SVG-2, SVG-3 variables and use it in HTML.
Something like:

```
<i class="svg-image">{SVG-1}</i>.
<i class="svg-image-2">{SVG-2}</i>
<i class="svg-image-3">{SVG-3}</i>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: something like `document.querySelectorAll('.svg-image-2').forEach(i => i.innerHTML = "NEW_SVG_2_TAG")`?

Comment: can you please share what you have attempted to solve this?

Comment: Why do you have 3 different classes? Classes are usually used when you have multiple elements with the same class, so you can operate on them as a group by looping over them.

Comment: see todays answer to an SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74457079/properly-used-of-svg-on-a-web/74460194#74460194

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this from within the HTML alone. To achieve this effect, you need to use JavaScript. In JavaScript, edit the [DOM node's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) using something like `document.querySelector(".svg-image").textContent = SVG_1;`. If you're looking to insert actual HTML instead of just text, look into [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead of `textContent`. If you want to have this kind of syntax as well as reactivity, look into [React](https://reactjs.org/) or [Solid](https://www.solidjs.com/) which can help out with this.

Hope this helps!